# Get Data from Map in Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get title and body from my Firestore data structure, data structure shown in the picture below. I tried this code, with this I got complete data but I want title and body individually.

```
        let docRef = db.collection("test").document("test")

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let notidata = document, notidata.exists {
            let notiDetail = notidata.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(notiDetail)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
```

Kindly help me out with that.

[image]

Comment: got answer. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105966/get-map-data-from-cloud-firestore)