# Get map data from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get map data from cloud `Firestore`,this is java code I need to access the same database in swift. I attached the java code and database structure picture for reference.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference mDocRef = db.collection("hmdhAcademy").document("notifications");

    mDocRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

        if ( task.isSuccessful() ) {

            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

            if ( documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists() ){

                notificationList = (ArrayList) documentSnapshot.get("userNotifications");
                adapter = new NotificationAdapter(this,notificationList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(NotificationActivity.this,"Check Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

if ( list.get(i) instanceof  HashMap ){

        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NotificationDetail.class);

        String title = (String)((HashMap)list.get((list.size()-1)-i)).get("title");
        String body = (String)((HashMap)list.get((list.size()-1)-i)).get("body");
        String image = (String)((HashMap)list.get((list.size()-1)-i)).get("notiImage");
        String detail = (String)((HashMap)list.get((list.size()-1)-i)).get("detail");
}
```

[image]

I need the same title, body, notiImage and detail.

Please help me with that, I'm looking for an answer anywhere but failed.

Comment: can you show your printed data

Comment: this java code from my friend, actually we both working on the same app, I'm on iOS he is on Andriod. in Jave code, he gets the Hello World! in the title and so on.

I did not apply this code in swift ye but want to and need help to write code for swift

Comment: Just show me what you get when you print document.data() n your swift code

Comment: I got this print result with below code
 
Print Result:

["userNotifications": <__NSArrayM 0x600002328660>(
{
    body = "Open the app to explore!";
    detail = "This is the best notification ever!";
    notiImage = "Notification Image URL";
    title = "Hello World!";
}
)
]

Comment: Okay just try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
if let document = document, document.exists {
    print(document.data()!)
    let userNotifications = document.data()["userNotifications"] as? [[String:Any]]
    for notificaton in userNotifications  {
        let body = notificaton["body"] as? String ?? ""
        let title = notificaton["title"] as? String ?? ""
        print(body, title)

    }

} else {
    print("Document does not exist")
}
}
```

Or try this way:

1. Create a struct

   ```
   struct usernotifcatons {

   var body: String = ""
   var detail: String = ""
   var notiImage: String = ""
   var title: String = ""


   init(notificationData: [String:Any]) {

   let body = notificationData["body"] as? String ?? ""
   self.body = body

   let detail = notificationData["detail"] as? String ?? ""
   self.detail = detail

   let notiImage = notificationData["notiImage"] as? String ?? ""
   self.notiImage = notiImage

   let title = notificationData["title"] as? String ?? ""
   self.title = title
    }

   }
   ```
2. Create a variable in your ViewController:

   ```
   var allNotifications: [usernotifcatons] = [usernotifcatons]()
   ```
3. Map all your data in one line in your firestore code

   ```
   docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
   if let document = document, document.exists {
   print(document.data()!)
   let userNotifications = document.data()?["userNotifications"] as? [[String:Any]]
   for data in userNotifications! {
               self.allNotifications.append(usernotifications(notificationData: data))
           }
   print(self.allNotifications)

     } else {
   print("Document does not exist")
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: great, it's working thank you, but there is a little problem, 

when I add another map and put notification data in it (i want to show multiple notifications) code print both maps titles(map 0 and map 1). how can I solve this? can I store all maps in the array and after that access every map data

Comment: If that data is in your notificatonlist you can access it and it is better if you create a class or struct to access your data....accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: this is the printed data whn i add 2nd map

["userNotifications": <__NSArrayM 0x600000c2aeb0>(
{
    body = "Open the app to explore!";
    detail = "This is the best notification ever!";
    notiImage = "Notification Image URL";
    title = "Hello World!";
},
{
    body = "body 2";
    detail = "detail 2";
    notiImage = "Image URL 2";
    title = "title 2";
}
)
]
Open the app to explore!
Hello World!
body 2
title 2

Comment: can you help me to build struct or class for multiple notifications data

Comment: Yeah sure just wait for few moments

Comment: see the updated now you can easily use your struct in tableView and collectionView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193234/discussion-between-wings-and-sohaib-siddique).